# how to post account/update_profile_image in twitter c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am having trouble implementing Twitter's [update profile image] method. Does anyone have any sample code for passing an image as raw multiart data to the Twitter API?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried. Post your code, etc

Comment: i want to change my twitter profile image by using twitter rest api

Comment: There are several versions of the twitter api.  I assume you are using an SDK if so what version. If not are you writing raw sockets to access the api? Using TCP client, WebClient, HttpWebRequests. You need to provide more information about what specifically you are trying to do and what problem you are having.

Comment: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json" i am use this api from https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_image how to use it

Comment: See my answer. You need to simply convert an image to base64 and append it as the value of the image query string. There is c# code in the answer to get this value or you can use an online base64 tool.

Answer (score 3):

Using the API directly for this is straightforward it only requires that you perform a POST request to the api endpoint and append the base64 of the image as the value of the image query string.

POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json?image=base64data

Reading an image file and converting it to base64 is straightforward as well.

```
string base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("image.jpg"));
string url= "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json?image=" + base64Data
```

The more complicated part is authenticating against the API in the first place. Assuming you are already doing that the code above will will satisfy your needs.

If not you need to look at a library or an SDK such as LinqToTwitter. There are numerous examples on the wiki.

If you are going to be manually coding the request, see the API documentation for how requests should be constucted: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests

Using Tweetinvi: https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/

```
private class AuthCredentials
{
    public string ConsumerKey = "ConsumerKey";
    public string ConsumerSecret = "ConsumerSecret";
    public string AccessToken = "AccessToken";
    public string AccessTokenSecret = "AccessTokenSecret";
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var creds = new AuthCredentials();
    Auth.SetUserCredentials(creds.ConsumerKey, creds.ConsumerSecret, creds.AccessToken, creds.AccessTokenSecret);
    var data = File.ReadAllText("myimage.jpg");
    Account.UpdateProfileImage(data);
}
```

Twitter's API documents has a list of libraries for a variety of languages: https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries

Comment: how to call this api is there any format in my code format this is not work

Comment: Look into using a library or an SDK. I have used LinqToTwitter in the past.

Comment: else if(Method == "POST" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonPath))
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }  is this good